# js in html on gcp (local testing) doesn't work

Tags: javascript, python, google-cloud-platform, app.yaml

I work with google cloud platform under front-end application with python.

I try to run java script function from a separate file while debugging on a local machine with Google App Engine Launcher.

I use python also.

I have four files in the same folder:

app.yaml:

```yaml
application: test
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

handlers:
- url: .*
  script: main.app

- url: /.js
  static_files: /test.js
  upload: /test.js  

libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: "2.5.2"
- name: jinja2
  version: latest
- name: markupsafe
  version: latest
```

main.html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>HELLO</title>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
    <input type="button" name="Test" value="Test" onclick="testclick()"/>
</body>

</html>
```

main.py:

```python
import jinja2
import os
import webapp2

template_env = jinja2.Environment(
    loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader(os.getcwd()))

class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        template = template_env.get_template('main.html')        
        self.response.out.write(template.render())

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainHandler)
], debug=True)
```

and test.js:

```javascript
function testclick()
{
    alert('module test.js');
}
```

I get an error
GET http://localhost:8080/test.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
while clicking on the button.

How should I modify yaml-file for fixing this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The order of the handlers in the `app.yaml` file matters, your `/.js` entry will never be hit because it'll be matched by the `.*` pattern first, you need to reverse their order.

So, I edited your `app.yaml` file and it works fine for me.

```yaml
application: test
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

handlers:
- url: /test.js
  static_files: test.js
  upload: test.js  

- url: .*
  script: main.app

libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: "2.5.2"
- name: jinja2
  version: latest
- name: markupsafe
  version: latest
```